# swift UITabbaritem colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how to use the colors I want for my `tabBar`.

I know how to change the background, I also know how to change the `tabbar.item` colors and text but I can't understand how to:

- the default gray color of the unselected tab bar item
- to change the color if the item is selected (and I'm using rendering mode always original cause I can't find another way to remove the default gray color from the non selected tab bar item)

  ```
  override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {

      super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

      tabBarItem.title = "test"
      tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "first.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)   

  }
  ```

how can I use the color I want, in the state I want?

Answer (score 11):

A `UITabBar` has a `tintColor` property, but this sets the tint for the selected image, not the unselected one. You're setting the unselected image correctly AFAIK. For changing the colour of the selected image, you can use the `tintColor` on the `UITabBar` (if you want all the images to have the same tint), or set your `UITabBarItem`'s `selectedImage` with the rendering mode as `AlwaysOriginal`.

```
tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "first-selected")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
```

I've set the UIImage to be an unwrapped optional because you probably want it to crash if there is no image file. It'll help ensure your images are actually being loaded, rather than silently failing :-)

You may also want to set the colour for the label or your text won't match your image colours. The below sets the defaults for all `UITabBarItem`'s, but you can set (or override) it on a per item basis.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes({NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()}, forState:.Selected)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes({NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()}, forState:.Normal)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you do it in **swift 3 / 4**

```
  UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue], for: .selected)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want:

- a selected `tabBarItem` to display a *colour image*
- an unselected `tabBarItem` to display a *greyed-out image*

Then you need to ensure the relevant image assets in XCode are set as `Render as: Default`, then:

```
let image = SomeImage
tabBarItem.image = image
tabBarItem.selectedImage = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

This ensures that for the `selectedImage` case you are forcing the image to display as the original, and in any other situation it will render with the expected tints applied.